# mixing 2 signals question

Tags: mixing, looping

[edit: sorry for the misuse]
[Edit again: the looper is the digitech jamman Express xt]
I have to mix two mono signals: the output of a piezo mic and the output of a looper. the piezo goes both into the looper and to the line out, the looper output goes to a small amp i'll use as monitor for the loops only and to the same line out of the piezo.
also, i have a on/off switch between the piezo and the looper in order to avoid that the piezo output goes to the amp too.
so, basically, how to mix the output AND the input of an effect pedal without get the output back into the input?
i promise it's simple, really, only i don't know how to be clear, i'm italian after all :D

Comment: It might be clear if you explain what the phrase "sort of Larsen" is supposed to mean, or maybe correct it if that's not what you meant to write. Also if you tell us exactly (device, brand, model) what the outputs are coming from and what the inputs are going to.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to split your input signal, apply an effect to on half and then mix it back in.  No?

Comment: what kind of looper is it?

Comment: Just edited the question

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is called an Isolated Signal Splitter (sometimes called isolated guitar splitter). They have a transformer in them that keeps the signals for mixing with each other, allowing you to send separated signal into the effect.

If you are trying to actually mix the source and the effect before sending to an amp, then a mini mixer is what you want. You can find them in 2 to 4 channel versions, and will allow you to not only isolate the signals, but blend them back together.

Depending on your amplifier, you also could use the effect send/return if it has one. You take out of the effect send, put it into your effect, the put the output of the effect to the return. The amp will isolate the instrument signal for you. These jacks are often found on the back of an amp.